# Marshalling java proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jaxb

Can someone suggest an approach for marshalling and unmarshalling javaassyst proxy objects. I'd like to have something like JAXB or xstream approach.
Currently i see only one way to solve this problem

- create flat class which hosts the same attributes as proxy (this is a problem because i have about 300 attributes)
- write some reflection to map properties (or uses something like DOZER) (this could be to slow and inefficient)
- use xstream to serialize object use mapper to transfer proxy -> flat -> xml or xml -> flat -> proxy

This approach seems inefficient, does anyone have some better ideas?

Comment: Marshalling a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`?  The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

If the base class is annotated with Jackson json annotations, then the fact that it is a proxy will not affect the marshalling.  Here is an example of marshalling a proxy object as JSON.

```
import javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler;
import javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory;
import javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Bar bar = create(Bar.class);
            bar.setBar("something");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String out = mapper.writeValueAsString(bar);
            Bar inBar = mapper.readValue(out, bar.getClass());
            System.out.println("Unmarshalled: " + inBar.getClass().getName() + " , bar: " + inBar.getBar());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static <T> T create(Class<T> classs) throws Exception {
        ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
        factory.setSuperclass(classs);
        Class clazz = factory.createClass();
        MethodHandler handler = new MethodHandler() {

            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object self, Method overridden, Method forwarder,
                                 Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println("I could be used for AOP "+overridden.getName());
                return forwarder.invoke(self, args);
            }
        };
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
        ((ProxyObject) instance).setHandler(handler);
        return (T) instance;
    }
}

class Bar{
    @JsonProperty
    private String bar = "bar";

    String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```